# 2.5" SSD SATA 6.0 will fit into Lenovo H430 Desktop?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Lenovo H430 desktop and I wanted to know whether I could install a 2.5" SSD hard drive in it? It has 4 SATA connectors on the motherboard, but I wasn't sure if I had to get a 3.5" SSD or if a 2.5" would work fine.

Also, how would one fit the drive into the computer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For hardware recommendations, the best place to go would be review sites where they put the hardware through its paces. Also, reading through the user reviews on sites like TigerDirect can be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.5 will work fine in a Desktop, you may need 2.5 to 3.5 adapter rails though.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was reading online and found there are adapter brackets and then mounting rails. What's the difference? Do you plug the SSD into a adapter bracket and then connect the SATA cable to the bracket whereas the mounting kits just hold the SSD and you still connect the cables to the SSD?

Comment: Brackets just allow you to mount the drive in a 3.5 inch bay, cables are the same for 2.5 and 3.5 drives